# How can a dependency (registered in nested LifetimeScope) be resolved from autofac container

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac, event-bus

Is there any way to resolve the dependency (which is actually registered in nested LifetimeScope, not in container) from container?

**Explanation of Actual Implementation:**

I have `ApplicationContext` class (with `IServiceProvider` injected in its constructor) containing current-user's basic info. It first resolves `IHttpContextAccessor` from `serviceProvider`, then extract user's info from `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext`. `ApplicationContext` class is injected into all repositories/services.

But, In some static classes, I am resolving `ApplicationContext` class from static IoC class (autofac container wrapped in it). And I think this is the only solution, because I can't inject into static constructor.

I am implementing event-bus for which I have created `EventBusContext` class which receives user-info from Event Data.

`ApplicationContext` class try to resolve `EventBusContext` from `IServiceProvider` and extract user-info from it **ONLY** if it gets `HttpContext` as null (*which means this execution is not started from Http Request*).

Once `EventBus` class receives an event from RabbitMQ, it creates `EventBusConext` class, add users info into it and registers it on the fly into newly created nested `LifetimeScope` then resolves the `EventHandler` class and invoke Handle method (via reflection).

**Everything works perfect! The issue occurs ONLY when** `EventHandler` uses any class which resolves `ApplicationContext` class from static `IoC` class, because then static `IoC` class internally tries to resolves `EventBusContext` from autofac container (which is wrapped in it) but it fails to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to focus on the initial question to start:

> Is there any way to resolve the dependency (which is actually registered in nested LifetimeScope, not in container) from container?

**The short answer is no.** If something is registered/added in a child scope, there's no way a parent scope will know about it.

Autofac scopes are hierarchical. [There is a lot of documentation on this including a diagram to illustrate that.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html)

Trying to boil it down to "rules," we could say:

- Registration "rules":

  - You can register things into the root container.
  - When you create a child lifetime scope, you can add new registrations that exist just for that scope.
- Resolution "rules":

  - When you resolve a service it will only know about things that are registered in the lifetime scope from which you're resolving and any parents.
  - If you resolve a singleton it will always resolve from the root lifetime scope, including all its dependencies.
  - Child scopes know about parent scopes.
  - Parent scopes do not hold references or "know" about child scopes.

This is very simplified but is close enough to illustrate the point.

If you have things added dynamically to a child lifetime scope you'll only have access to them in that child lifetime scope and any child scopes you create from there.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<A>();
var container = builder.Build();

// This will work (though it's recommended you avoid resolving things
// from containers because it can lead to memory leaks).
// https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html
container.Resolve<A>();

// This will NOT work. The container doesn't have B in it.
container.Resolve<B>();

using(var scope1 = container.BeginLifetimeScope(b => b.RegisterType<B>())
{
  // This will work. The child scope knows about parent registrations.
  scope1.Resolve<A>();

  // This will also work. The registration was added to the scope.
  scope1.Resolve<B>();

  // This will STILL NOT WORK. The parent does NOT know about child scopes.
  container.Resolve<B>();

  using(var scope2 = scope1.BeginLifetimeScope())
  {
    // These will work. The child scope knows about parent registrations.
    scope2.Resolve<A>();
    scope2.Resolve<B>();

    // This will STILL NOT WORK.
    container.Resolve<B>();
  }
}
```

There is no hackery or workaround for this. It's intentionally hierarchical.

If you have something that needs access to request-level items (or otherwise needs things that are registered in a child lifetime scope dynamically) the *only way to get them* is to resolve from that child lifetime scope or a nested child.

Getting more specific to the goal:

From the implementation description, you have some things that intentionally run outside a request and resolve from the root container (again, not a great idea, but it is what it is). If those things suddenly need items that are registered on the fly by a request, then you have basically two options, both of which are "you need to change your architecture/design."

1. Switch all the items that run "outside a request" to run "inside a request" so they have access to the dynamically registered things.
2. Change method signatures or whatever so the dynamically registered things aren't *dependencies* of the "outside-the-request" items - make those dynamic things get passed in as method parameters.

Actually providing a fully updated design or "working code" illustrating either of those things is more a consulting effort than an answer to the question. Unfortunately, though, the solution to getting to that per request data means you need to change your design.

Comment: As I already mentioned these are static classes, so **implementing First option is impossible** by which I mean there is no option to inject the dependencies into static class so that static class stay inside a request. **Second option is more practical and also viable.**